# How to avoid duplicate message when 2 applications with different port listening on same kafka topic through 2 different ports?

Tags: spring, maven, apache-kafka, apache-camel, apache-karaf

My spring boot application is consuming (apache camel) messages from kafka topic.

Same application (8080 running on eclipse & 9090 running on intellij) is running on two different ports (8080 & 9090) on the same machine, so the two port application listening on same topic.

How can I manage to get a message to the specific port consumer?

For example, if my topic receives "Hi" message it gets both of my consumers (8080 & 9090).

I don't want that same message receives on both consumers.

"Hi" message only consumes by 8080 application and "Hello" message consumes by 9090 application.

At a time only one application get the chance to receive message and next time chance is for second application. Like cyclic. Could you help me to find a solution for this issue, please?

Comment: Unclear how many partitions your topic has, but even with a single group id, messages aren't guaranteed to be delivered one by one to separate consumers (the default poll size per consumer is 500)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use same `groupId` for each consumer. Only one consumer of will receive a message if they use same group id.

The consumers with the same group id will create something called Consumer group. Only one consumer of a consumer group can consume a distinct message from a topic, other consumers will not be able to consume the same message.

You can set a default group id in `application.properties`

```
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=test_group
```

Or you can set groupId at `@KafkaListener`

```
@KafkaListener(id = "consumer2", topics = "topic", groupId = "test_group")
public void consumeLog(){

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this information really helpfull. I'm new for kafka. Thanks again